# How do I instantiate a Register object in Java using the jamod library?

Tags: java, modbus, modbus-tcp

I'm currently working with jamod in order to set up a small control system for work. We are working with several PLCs and I need to use the MODBUS protocol for communication. I have been able to read the values that are measured by the controllers, however I am unsuccessful in writing to the controller (adjusting amperage).

My question is, how do I instantiate a Register object using jamod?

```
Register[] reg_1 = new Register[5];
        reg_1[0].setValue(16000);
```

This doesn't work. Essentially I would like to set the value of the register at position 0 to the integer 16000. I have also tried using

```
reg_1[0].setValue(Integer.parseInt("16000"));
```

I've been looking through the jamod documentation and can't find any way of creating a proper register object nor any examples of how to set a proper register to write.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be most grateful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The proper way to set up a Register[] for writing, in my case, was setting up several SimpleRegisters made up of UINT_16s,then throwing them into the Register[] array like so:

```
        Register reg1 = new SimpleRegister(48911);
        Register reg2 = new SimpleRegister(23593);
        Register reg3 = new SimpleRegister(48911);
        Register reg4 = new SimpleRegister(23593);

        WriteMultipleRegistersRequest req = new WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(41200,new Register[]{reg1,reg2,reg3,reg4});
        WriteMultipleRegistersResponse res = new WriteMultipleRegistersResponse();
```

Where 41200 was the reference point to which the register writing starts. You can do this with multiple amounts, even 1 or 100, and adjust your register amounts accordingly. In my case I was sending and receiving two 8bit words from the modbus so I had two registers per value.